# Toggling Less/More button in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a code that partially load and display two comments. Another button, `More comments` is attached and it loads the remaining comments via AJAX. 
The `More comments` is then replaced with `Less comments` button. Now what I want is whenver the less comment button is clicked, the comments should be hidden and 
the `Less comments` button should be replaced with `More comments` button which can be clicked to display the hidden comments. 
It actaully does replace the `Less comments` button with expected one but it hides it together with the comments.

```
<div class='feeds'>
    <div class='comments'>
        <div class='comment_data>
      <div class = ' per_comment '>
        <p> slideToggle!</p>
      </div>
      <div class = 'per_comment '>
        <p> classToggle!</p>
      </div>
    <button class='morecomments ' value='7 ' name = 'more ' type='submit '>
     More comments</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery code to fetch more comments via AJAX. This is working fine.

```
$(".morecomments").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var post_id = $(this).val();
    var user_id = $(".user_id").text();
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "comments.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            post: post_id,
            user: user_id
        },
        dataType: "html"
    });
    request.done(function (msg) {
        $this.prev('.per_comment').html(msg);
        $this.replaceWith("<button class='lesscomments' value='7' name = 'more' type='submit'>Less comments</button>");
    });
});
```

The jQuery code to hide the comments. Clicking this will hide the comments but the `replaceWith` button also disappear:

```
$('.comment_data').on('click', ".lesscomments", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.comment_data').slideToggle();
    $this.replaceWith("<button class='morecomments' value='7' name = 'more' type='submit'>More comments</button>");
});
```

Any workable solution will be immensely appreciated...

Comment: Be carefull, <button class='morecomments' value='7' name = 'more' type='submit'> .. if it is NOT in a <form> .. what is the browser default behavior supposed to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
//use event delegation here also as the button is created dynamically
$(".comment_data").on('click', '.morecomments', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $pc = $this.prev('.per_comment');
    //if the comments are already loaded then don't load it again just display it
    if ($pc.data('loaded')) {
        $this.replaceWith("<button class='lesscomments' value='7' name = 'more' type='submit'>Less comments</button>");
        $pc.slideDown();
    } else {
        var post_id = $(this).val();
        var user_id = $(".user_id").text();
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "comments.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                post: post_id,
                user: user_id
            },
            dataType: "html"
        });
        request.done(function (msg) {
            $pc.html(msg).data('loaded', true);
            $this.replaceWith("<button class='lesscomments' value='7' name = 'more' type='submit'>Less comments</button>");
        });
    }
});
$('.comment_data').on('click', ".lesscomments", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.prev('.per_comment').slideUp();
    $this.replaceWith("<button class='morecomments' value='7' name = 'more'>More comments</button>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your button is inside the `<div class='comment-data'>` that you are hiding.  If you move the button outside this div, it should work.

Comment: It only replaces the buttons, it stopped AJAX from loading more commnets.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/LqDxG/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="feeds">
    <div class="comments">
        <div class="comment_data">
            <div class="per_comment">
                <p>slideToggle!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="per_comment">
                <p>classToggle!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="per_comment comment">
                <p>slideToggle!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="per_comment comment">
                <p>slideToggle!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="per_comment comment">
                <p>slideToggle!</p>
            </div>
            <button class="morecomments showMoreLess" value="7" name="more" type="submit">More comments</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".showMoreLess", function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("morecomments")) {
        $(this).html("Less Comment");
        $(this).removeClass("morecomments").addClass("lesscomments");
    } else {
        $(this).html("More Comment");
        $(this).removeClass("lesscomments").addClass("morecomments");
    }
    $('.comment').slideToggle();
});
```